Database exception while starting spring boot application
I'm using custom port of mssql connection, everything seems right but when I start application I get below exception.
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost:1434, port 1433 has failed. Error: "localhost:1434. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext.getQueryResults(ExtractionContext.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:289) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.3.Final.jar:6.5.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost:1434, port 1433 has failed. Error: "localhost:1434. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:233) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.4.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.convertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:284) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.4.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2592) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.4.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:720) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.4.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3770) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.4.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3355) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.4.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:3180) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.4.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1963) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.4.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1259) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.6.4.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:137) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:360) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:461) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:550) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:98) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:na]

Below is application.yml
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=localhost:1434;databaseName=trading;encrypt=false
    username: trading
    password: trading
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Database is running in local and able to connect with SQL editor. Exception looks like it is related to connection but not sure what's wrong.

You should include the full exception stack trace. We can't see the exception type (class) or message

@Dónal My bad, updated the exception trace now

Do you have access to your db from Some DB UI client?

@talexmovedtoCodidact Yes

If your port is 1434 then try jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;serverName=localhost;databaseName=trading;encrypt=false

@seenukarthi If you provide the servername and portnumber like that, you don't even need to specify the serverName property.

According to the documentation, the serverName property does not support a port number:


serverName (Optional) - Is the address of the server to connect to. This address can be a DNS or IP address, or it can be localhost or 127.0.0.1 for the local computer. If not specified in the connection URL, the server name must be specified in the properties collection.


There is however another property called portNumber:


portNumber (Optional) - Is the port to connect to on serverName. The default is 1433. If you're using the default port, you don't have to specify the port, nor the preceding : in the URL.


So the solution is to use the following URL:
jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=localhost;portNumber=1434;databaseName=trading;encrypt=false

Alternatively, you can also provide the servername and portnumber without using connection properties:
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databaseName=trading;encrypt=false

